# Error 53 - The network path was not found

Tags: windows, active-directory, networking

I have a machine in my Active Directory Domain that I can no longer "net view" from other machines in the domain.

This is a Windows XP Pro machine.  It is hosting a VMWare virtual of my Domain Controller.

If I attempt to net view [machine name] I get system error 53, The network path was not found.

This is not a DNS issue, the same thing happens with the machine's IP.

I don't think it's a firewall issue, I turned the firewall off on this machine.

As I mentioned, it has worked in the past, and then stopped for no reason that I can see.  I (intentionally) didn't change the software.

I CAN get to the VMs hosted on this machine, can connect to their shares, net view them, etc.  All other machines can see each other.  In fact, the problem machine can see other machines and access their shares just fine.

I tried removing the machine from the domain and re-adding it.
I tried deleting the shares and recreating them.

Not sure how to troubleshoot this any further.  Any ideas?

Comment: It is generally not good practice to have a VM host be a member of a domain where the domain controller is a guest of that host. It's a circular reference: the host may require resources on the guest when the guest is not available, such as at boot time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why net view machinename is used (I've never used it personally).  Found a good article in KB.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142027

I'd confirm port 139 is open using telnet.  telnet name 139

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something in NetBIOS is not behaving.

You could try making sure NetBIOS over TCP/IP is still enabled on the relevant network adapters. There are also some services involved, "Browser", "Server" and "Client", I think. Make sure those are running, too.

The `nbtstat` tool could also be useful when troubleshooting this problem: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940106.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without looking at network traces and event logs. Also have had weird issues with vmware shared folders for the guest VM. I'd disable that as a troubleshooting step. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012140 shows how VMware shared folders can affect guest VMs sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently (`net view` returning error 53 for any server, even when supplied with the IP address; `nbtstat` working fine).

It seems that most people face this problem when their `NetworkProvider` registry entry got malformed: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/04/UNC-Drive-Mapping-Failures-Network-name-cannot-be-found (TL;DR: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order` key should contain `ProviderOrder` value, consisting of several names separated by commas; `LanmanWorkstation` should come first, or second after `RDPNP`; there should be no empty entries, leading commas etc). However, in my case, everything was in order in that key.

It turned out that there is a `TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper` which for some reason switched into a "disabled" state (probably due to some rogue update). Once I switched it back on, everything started to work.

Answer (score 0):

When I went to NIC binding order, my management interface (with the default gateway) was not on the top and did NOT have the bindings for "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" and "Client for Microsoft Network".
I had to enable both (for IPv4). I also dragged the management interface to the top in the binding order.
I also went into interface properties, and disabled Netbios completely.
Then I was able to join the domain.